# Javascript - not replace object properties in assignment of objects

Tags: javascript

When assigning objects in javascript how do we determine the properties already existing in the assigned object is not being replaced. For example say:

```
var foo = {
   property1: "a",
   property3: "d"
}

var bar = {
   property1 : "b",
   property2 : "c"
}
```

then

```
a = b
```

would replace `property1` in `foo` with `b`. In the context I'm considering, we are not sure whether the property1 of `foo` is existing when the assignment happens. So when assigning the option is to check if `property1` exists, if not only then assign the `property1` from `b`. So simple `a=b` assignment is not an option. So is there a way to assign an object which will only append the properties which are not existing in the object assigned to, while not replacing the already existing ones.

I guess one way to do it would be to :

```
for(var prop in b){
   if(!(a[prop])){
      a[prop] = b[prop]; 
   }
}
```

Is there a better shorthand way?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand you - `a` and `b` are undefined in your example. Did you mean `foo = bar`?

Comment: @Amadan - That is absolutely true. Anyway my comment doesn't seem to do what Phabtar is trying to do so please ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like jQuery.extend: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/.

But assuming you don't want to use jQuery, here is a native JS implementation example that supports nested (deep) objects as well (http://jsfiddle.net/DqgYQ/):

```
function extend(target, src, deep){
    if(typeof target !== 'object' || typeof target === 'undefined' || target === null) return target;

    for(var prop in src){
        var value = target[prop];
        var copy = src[prop];

        if(deep && typeof copy === 'object'){
            value = typeof value === 'undefined' ? {} : value;

            target[prop] = extend(value, copy, deep);
        }
        else{
            target[prop] = copy;
        }
    }

    return target;
};
```

See the fiddle for a working example.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a better solution without Jquery.

Comment: My solution isn't jQuery. It's native JS.